# Send a BLOB (.wav) generated in JavaScript to a Java Program (Servlet)

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, blob, file-transfer

For a project I have to record audio on the browser over JavaScript, send this Audiofile to a Java Program on the server on which the page is loaded and work with it there.

So far I managed to create the blob with the type of .wav and (for testing) download it on the browser directly.

How can I transfer the blob file to the Java Servlet? I also tested around with URL-Objects but without any success.

Comment: So post the data to the server

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE. We do not want to wait for a week. DELETE your question and ask when you have code

Comment: I'm not an expert on JavaScript but here's one way you might send data: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find those already existing question somehow. But that's helping a lot!